# pyinstaller compiled scripts crash because of missing modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've tried compiling a Python program on my Mac, and all went well. I then moved to ubuntu, and can't even compile a hello world correctly:
I wrote the simplest hello world:

```
print("hello world")
```

then tried compiling it using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile hello.py
```

everything seemed to be fine, until I tried running it:

```
dist/hello
```

and got the following traceback:

```
[2886] mod is NULL - structTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/struct.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_struct'
[2886] mod is NULL - pyimod02_archiveTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+g5f91905-py3.6.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_archive.py", line 28, in <module>
    import struct
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'struct'
[2886] mod is NULL - pyimod03_importersTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+g5f91905-py3.6.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyimod02_archive import ArchiveReadError, ZlibArchiveReader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod02_archive'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+g5f91905-py3.6.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 15, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod03_importers'
[2886] Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap
```

It seems weird as I don't import any modules explicitly, but I followed a suggestion to add the missing modules in hello.spec under hiddenimports. so I added

```
hiddenimports=['_struct', 'struct', 'pyimod02_archive','pyimod03_importers']
```

and tried compiling with

```
pyinstaller --onefile hello.spec
```

but got the exact same error as before when I tried to run the exe file.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using pyinstaller 3.4.dev0+g5f91905 with Python 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: I'm experiencing the same kind of issue. Did you find a solution to this?